# Recover local changes in git repository after a replace in repo root dir

Tags: git

Any idea how to recover local changes in a git repo after a `find . -type f | xargs sed -i 's/[\t ]*$//g'` in repo root dir?

Comment: From the command you ran, it sounds like you might have also changed the object files and packs in the `.git` directory, in which case you've screwed your local history, and there's no way to tell how screwed. Follow the advice given in the below answers to undo changes to working tree files, then (if you can) use `git format-patch` to make a patch file of each branch that only appears locally. Then clone a brand new repository from upstream, and apply those patches to your new clone. Then go read about keeping backups.

Comment: I was not able to recove my changes. I cloned the repo again and have redone the work. Luckily, the corrupted repo didn't have a lot of unpushed changes.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you lost your local changes. Next time you're going to do a potentially damaging `find`, first run `find` on its own (with no -exec and not piped to another command) and check to see the output only has the files you expect. `find` is a complicated tool and very easy to get wrong like that: you can tell by how the two answerers read your question and didn't realise your command would change the files in `.git` too.

Comment: Was your problem solved? If so it would be nice if you could accept Mark's answer if it helped or provide your own so other people could benefit from the knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I misunderstood the question at first, I think I should clarify that the problem here is that the command you've run will also have rewritten files in the git's `objects` directory.  (Clearly the files in your working tree can be restored using the usual suggestions of `git reset --hard`, with the usual caveat that uncommitted local changes will be lost.)

I haven't had to deal with this situation myself, but I would suggest the following:

1. Copy your corrupted repository to somewhere save just in case trying to repair the damage makes things worse.
2. Try running: `git fsck` to assess the damage - among other checks, this will see which files' contents no longer match their hashes.
3. Try to find any clone of the repository that was last fetched from before the corruption (and carefully preserve a copy of it).  You can use this in place of the corrupted repository if you're careful to update `.git/config` correctly and get the file permissions right.

Comment: Git object files were corrupted, I'm not able to execute this command

Comment: @AlanEvangelista: sorry, I misunderstood - I've changed my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try:

`git reset --hard HEAD`

This is to discard all modifications in tracked files and revert the working directory to the state of HEAD

Comment: Git object files were corrupted, I'm not able to execute this command